# Rigify locks custom DEF- bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

So I have this old rig I want to merge with a Rigify rig. As suggested in the docs, I parented them and labeled them all as raw_copy. The next thing I'm supposed to do is rename them DEF- (and painstakingly rename the vertex groups I guess, but I have a script for that), but here is where I run into trouble.

If I *don't* name them DEF-, then "deform" isn't enabled and I have to manually enable it for each bone.

If  I *do* name them DEF-, then deform is enabled, *but* all transforms are locked and I have to manually unlock them. Also, now the bones are in a hidden layer by default.

Why are the DEF- bones getting locked? Is there something I'm missing? As it is, it's easier to forgo the naming convention altogether and just use a script to enable deform. I'm using Blender 3.6.0, if that helps, but I had this problem in 3.5.1. as well.

Note: Super_copy works (though I still have to rename my old vertex groups), but that's no good if I need to keep my constraints.